# Processing 'It looks like you're mixing "active" and "static" modes.'

Tags: comments, processing

Processing keeps giving me this error when I run it even though it is just a print command. When I delete the comment block it works fine. Here's the code:

```java
/*
    float[] cortToPolar(int xcorr, int ycorr) {
    float returns[] = new float[2];
    returns[0]= degrees(tan(ycorr/xcorr));
    returns[1]= sqrt(pow(xcorr,2)+pow(ycorr,2));
    return returns;
}

float lawCos(int a, int b, int c) {
  return degrees(
     acos(
     (pow(a,2)+pow(b,2)-pow(c,2))/
       (2*a*b)
     )
  );
}
*/
print(0);
```

Why doesn't it like my comment?

Answer (score 13):

Processing runs in two separate modes: **static** or **active**

**Static** mode simply means it's a list of instructions/calls to existing functions (e.g. draw a bunch of lines then exit)

**Active** mode uses the **setup()** and **draw()** calls and runs continuously (gets updated every 'frame').

Only in active mode you are allowed to define own functions like `cortToPolar` and `lawCos` (regardless of the fact they are commented - this could be a Processing editor bug).

Use the `setup()` call to print because using setup will bring Processing into active mode.

```
/*
float[] cortToPolar(int xcorr, int ycorr) {
    float returns[] = new float[2];
    returns[0]= degrees(tan(ycorr/xcorr));
    returns[1]= sqrt(pow(xcorr,2)+pow(ycorr,2));
    return returns;
}

float lawCos(int a, int b, int c) {
  return degrees(
     acos(
     (pow(a,2)+pow(b,2)-pow(c,2))/
       (2*a*b)
     )
  );
}
*/
void setup(){
  print(0);
}
```

(Should you need to use **active** mode and control how `draw()` is called you can use [`noLoop()`](http://processing.org/reference/noLoop_.html) and [`loop()`](http://processing.org/reference/loop_.html).)

Answer (score 4):

The message could be shown when the actual problem is a syntax error. I encountered this error with the following (silly) code:

```
boolean state = false;

setup() {
  size(200, 800);
}

void draw() {
}
```

It is missing the 'void' modifier for the setup function. This is a syntax error (at least, it should be). But the Processing IDE gives you this "active vs. static" message instead.

So in this case, it should be `void setup() { }` rather than just `setup() { }`.