# Processing Khan Academy vs Processing 2

Tags: javascript, processing, khan-academy

So I made this on khan-academy and want to put it on my website.

https://www.khanacademy.org/cs/fade-away/4830224329998336

To convert this to JavaScript I put the code below in.  Unfortunately I get the error: you are mixing active and static modes.  Why does this work on Khan Academy Processing and not in normal Processing?  Also what other ways can I write this to make it work?

```
//don't forget to click!!!
background(2, 3, 3);

strokeWeight(2);
var x = random;

void setup(){
  size(500,500);
}




void draw(){
   fill(0, 0, 0, 20);
   rect(0,0, 400,400);
    var randomSize = random(20, 60);

     if (mouseIsPressed) { 

        noStroke();
        fill(random(0, 255), random(0, 255), random(0, 255), 373);

        } 

    else {
        noStroke();
        fill(255, 0, 0, 15);
        randomSize=50;
    }
    ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, randomSize, randomSize);
};
```

Comment: The answer to this question may be of interest to you. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658827/processing-it-looks-like-youre-mixing-active-and-static-modes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems with your code. First, you can't have function calls outside of `draw()` and `setup()`-- that's what is causing the "active vs static" error. Move them inside of `setup()`. Second, there is no such thing as `mouseIsPressed` in processing, but there is `mousePressed`. You also do not need a semicolon after the closing brace of `draw()`. You also use hard-coded values of `400` for drawing the rectangle, while the window itself is `500`x`500`. You shouldn't use hard-coded numbers like that anyway, use the built-in `width` and `height` constants. Lastly, you never use the variable `x`, so I commented it out. Here is code that works (and is cleaned up, formatting-wise).

```
//don't forget to click!!!

void setup() {
  size(500, 500);
  background(2, 3, 3);
  strokeWeight(2);
  //var x = random;
}

void draw() {
  fill(0, 0, 0, 20);
  rect(0, 0, width, height);
  var randomSize = random(20, 60);
  noStroke();

  if (mousePressed) { 
    fill(random(0, 255), random(0, 255), random(0, 255), 373);
  }  else {
    fill(255, 0, 0, 15);
    randomSize=50;
  }
  ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, randomSize, randomSize);
}
```

Comment: Thanks So Much! I figured out that I wasn't supposed to have functions outside of setup() but the mouseIsPressed was still messing me up.  I was really confused and this clears it up for me. Thanks also for the added advice!